# How can I get invoice ID given the $payment object in magento

Tags: magento, payment, invoice

Given this function in Magento:

```
public function capture(Varien_Object $payment, $amount)
{
      $order = $payment->getOrder();
      $order_id = $order->getId();

      $invoice = ????
      $invoice_id = $invoice->getId();
}
```

How can I get the invoice or invoice ID?

Comment: Are you writing this function to replace the Magento Functionality?

Answer (score 1):

The `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` has methods like `hasInvoices()` and `getInvoiceCollection()`:

```
public function capture(Varien_Object $payment, $amount)
{
      $order = $payment->getOrder();
      $order_id = $order->getId();

      if ($order->hasInvoices()) {
          $oInvoiceCollection = $order->getInvoiceCollection();
          foreach ($oInvoiceCollection as $oInvoice) {
              $invoice_id = $oInvoice->getId();
              // ...
          }
      }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Jurgen. That's helpful. Given that I have the collection of invoices, how can I select the last invoice id from that collection? See I am running this code within  my own capture method, which is called when an invoice is created in Magento admin. And I want to store the id of that invoice that triggered my method.

Comment: To get the last item of any `Varien_Data_Collection` you can use the `getLastItem()` method of the collection. But since you didn't tell us, which class contains your given `capture()` method and which method of which object calls your `capture()` method, we cannot know which specific invoice object you're after. It can be as easy as `$this->getId()`, but this depends on what process flow you've implemented exactly.

Comment: @JürgenThelen: I do have the same question. The `capture()` is in the payment method's model file which will be called when admin creates an invoice for an order.